# TRAMP method for Fedora's mock?

Tags: tramp

[Mock](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki) is a utility used by Fedora to build packages in `chroot`s.  For debugging, it would be nice to access files inside those `chroot`s with all the amenities Emacs has to offer.

Calling `mock -r fedora-26-i386 --shell` yields a shell inside the `fedora-26-i386` `chroot`:

```
[tim@passepartout ~]$ mock -r fedora-26-i386 --shell
INFO: mock.py version 1.4.8 starting (python version = 3.6.4)...
Start: init plugins
INFO: selinux disabled
Finish: init plugins
Start: run
Start: chroot init
INFO: calling preinit hooks
INFO: enabled root cache
INFO: enabled dnf cache
Start: cleaning dnf metadata
Finish: cleaning dnf metadata
INFO: enabled HW Info plugin
Finish: chroot init
Start: shell
<mock-chroot> sh-4.4#
```

How would a TRAMP method look like for that so that (for example, I assume treating `fedora-26-i386` as a host name is fitting) `/mock:fedora-26-i386:/etc/passwd` would access `/etc/passwd` in the shell brought up by `mock -r fedora-26-i386 --shell`?

Answer (score 1):

For its own tests, Tramp needs also a `mock` method. This is not Fedora's mock, but you might study how Tramp declares it in `tramp-tests.el`.